# Why does display:block interfere with opacity?

Tags: jquery, opacity, addclass, css

```
#load {
opacity: 0;
display: none; /* is this a bad idea ? */
background-color: tomato;
transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

#load.is-active {
        display: block; /* is this a bad idea ? */
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

When adding the .is-active class there is no fade-in. I tracked the problem down to `display:none/block`, as soon as they are removed the problem is solved.

Now my question is why. Why is the block interfering with opacity ?

Further more - How do I remove the `#load` from view to enable click events on what is beneath it, so hiding it only with opacity is a no-no. * (in my real life situation there is something under that you should be able to click on once the loading bar has been removed) *

I made this little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QKCbE/

Comment: When I click somewhere there's appearing a box with loading... but I don't see any transition. is that your problem?

Comment: It is stopping the transition, not the opacity.

Comment: use `fadeToggle()` from jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/QKCbE/1/

Comment: @Spokey That's the easiest solution. Since I need the transitions for infinite-scroll, I'm using fadeIn and fadeOut now, but I'm still curious about what causes the transition not to work with blocks...

Comment: @Norris just a hunch but I think `display` sets the `opacity` itself. In that case the `transition` won't have on what to work on, since the `opacity` is already `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go along with other means if your want to try to achieve the whole 'block' transition conundrum.

Something along these line:

```
div {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  opacity: 0; 
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
```